# How to make some table cell borders disappear when using the table-bordered class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My goal is to eliminate the top and bottom border of a specific table cell (`td`). I was able to remove the inside border, but the top and bottom border still there.

This is my html code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="w-8">Label 1</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
                <td class="w-2 no-top-bottom"></td>
                <th class="w-8">Label 2</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="w-8">Label 1</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
                <td class="w-2 no-top-bottom"></td>
                <th class="w-8">Label 2</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="w-8">Label 1</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
                <td class="w-2 no-top-bottom"></td>
                <th class="w-8">Label 2</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="w-8">Label 1</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
                <td class="w-2 no-top-bottom"></td>
                <th class="w-8">Label 2</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my css style

```
table td {
    position: relative;
}

table  input {

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    
}

.w-4 {
    width: 4%;
}

.w-8 {
    width: 8%;
}

.w-10 {
    width: 10%;
}

.w-40 {
    width: 40%;
}

.no-top-bottom {
    border-top: none !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

My problem is that the `td` element at the top and bottom still have a border. It just like the picture below. I woyuld like to remove the borders marked in yellow too.
[image: My problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were removing the border from the cell, but a border was also being added by the `.table-bordered` class on `<table>`.

Removing the border from the table will work:

```
table.table-bordered { border:none;}
```

The `.table-bordered` class will still add borders to all the cells, but won't force a border around the outside of the table, so your `.no-top-bottom` CSS will work now.

Working snippet:

```css
table.table-bordered { border:none;}

table td {
    position: relative;
}

table  input {

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    
}

.w-4 {
    width: 4%;
}

.w-8 {
    width: 8%;
}

.w-10 {
    width: 10%;
}

.w-40 {
    width: 40%;
}

.no-top-bottom {
    border-top: none !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="w-8">Label 1</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
                <td class="w-2 no-top-bottom"></td>
                <th class="w-8">Label 2</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="w-8">Label 1</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
                <td class="w-2 no-top-bottom"></td>
                <th class="w-8">Label 2</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="w-8">Label 1</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
                <td class="w-2 no-top-bottom"></td>
                <th class="w-8">Label 2</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="w-8">Label 1</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
                <td class="w-2 no-top-bottom"></td>
                <th class="w-8">Label 2</th>
                <td class="w-40"><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I still wondering why you have to add `border:none;` property to `.table-bordered`, why don't they make it default?

Comment: @ThangNguyen Glad to help! `.table-bordered` is a Bootstrap class so they made the decision to include the table border in their styling. In my opinion it makes sense for a class with that name - if it didn't have a border on the table itself, it might be a bit misleading. Having a separate border on the table even though the cells also have a border is not uncommon, you might want to style the outside of the table differently, e.g. with a bigger border or different colour. This can help you do that too :)